# Swift: change Bar Button Item in code

Tags: ios, swift

I am using swift. I have a Bar Button Item that I would like to change the Identifier from Play to Stop in code. Is this possible and how do you do It?

```
@IBOutlet var StartStopButton: UIBarButtonItem!


@IBAction func StartAlarm(sender: AnyObject) {

    onOffIndicator.hidden = false
    StartStopButton.Identifier = ?????

}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried so far? Post your code please.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't change the identifier so you have to set the whole bar button item. You have to do the following:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Stop, target: self, action: "startAlarm:")
```

To make it nicer you can define an array of `UIBarButtonSystemItem`s and an index like so:

```
let myArray = [UIBarButtonSystemItem.Start, UIBarButtonSystemItem.Stop]
var index = 0
```

Then you can do:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: myArray[++index % myArray.count], target: self, action: "startAlarm:")
```

By the way, remember to use non-capitalized function and variable names ;)

Answer (score -1):

## Swift 5

```
@IBOutlet var StartStopButton: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBAction func StartAlarm(sender: AnyObject) {
    onOffIndicator = !onOffIndicator
    if onOffIndicator {
    StartStopButton.image = UIImage(systemName: "stop")
    } else {
    StartStopButton.image = UIImage(systemName: "play")
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is not clear yet.